# What is the Best way to deserialize a null-terminated string in .NET?

Tags: .net, binaryreader

I am reading a message from my network connection which is serialized as a series of null-terminated strings (and other binary data)

I could read a char at a time using a BinaryReader, until I find a NULL.

Is there a more efficient way that is still simple? I'm expecting strings less than 64 chars in length, but they could be longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think reading byte by byte is a reasonable option, but I would use a [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) to minimize IO on the underlying stream.

Answer (score 2):

Read the whole thing into a string, then use String.Split to split on the nulls.

Remember that strings are not null-terminated in .NET.

Comment: He didn't say how long the whole message was (or even whether it terminates).  There's a good chance reading the whole thing is not feasible.

Comment: On the other hand there is not enough info in the question to be sure it is not feasible.  It is a good idea that may well help someone else if no the OP.

Comment: Actually there kind of is enough information if you read between the lines. He mentions he is obtaining the input data from a network connection, which implies using winpcap or simliar API. Therefore as Matthew said it is highly probable that he is pulling input from a continious stream of data.